# attribute grammar for regular expression

Tags: programming-languages

how to write this attribute grammar?

I am not sure about the production with star.

Design a context-free grammar for regular expressions. Make this an attribute grammar with a setvalued attribute attached to the start symbol that is the language (set of strings) denoted by the regular
expression. A regular expressions can be empty, a symbol, the concatenation of two regular expressions, two regular expressions separated by a vertical bar, a regular expression followed by a star,
or a regular expression in parentheses. E.g., for the regular expression ‘l(l|d)*’ your attribute
grammar should construct the (inﬁnite) set of all strings consisting of an l followed by zero or more
occurrences of either l or d.

Thanks.

Comment: my partial answer:


RE::= e {RE.set=empty} 

RE1::=(RE2) {RE1.set=RE2.set}

RE::=Symbol {RE.set={Symbol}}

RE1::=RE2+RE3 {RE1.set=RE2.set union RE3.set}

RE1::=RE2 {RE1=RE2.set}

| RE3 {RE1=RE3.set}

RE1::=RE2* {***no idea here!!***}

RE1::=(RE2) {RE1.set=RE2.set}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: there's a generalized form of set `union` involving an index set and a set-valued expression involving the index. It's written something like the following:

U <sub>i in I</sub> f(i)

For example, the set of rational numbers is equal to

U <sub>i in Z</sub> { i / j  |  j in Z, j != 0 }

(Z, usually written in "blackboard bold", is the set of all integers.)

Comment: but how to choose the symbol to repeat?